# lite-server for production use

Tags: angular, lite-server

I'm now learning Angular 2 and I can see that the tutorials are using [lite-server](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server) for serving static files. I've read that lite-server is a development-only server, but what's actually the reason it cannot be used in production? Thanks.